# SAPI (Microsoft Speech API) CoCreateInstance failed

Tags: c++, text-to-speech, sapi

I'm trying to run a SAPI sample from [a Microsoft sample page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

When I run the application (with VS2010), this line fails:

```
hr = cpVoice.CoCreateInstance( CLSID_SpVoice );
```

hr return an error code and all other code is not executed.

I don't know why I'm wrong,, because I think to use correctly the sample code in that page and I've never use this API before.

This is my complete main.cpp file. What I'm missing?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <sapi.h>
#include <sphelper.h>
#include <atlcomcli.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    CComPtr <ISpVoice>      cpVoice;
    CComPtr <ISpStream>     cpStream;
    CSpStreamFormat         cAudioFmt;

    //Create a SAPI Voice
    hr = cpVoice.CoCreateInstance( CLSID_SpVoice );

    //Set the audio format
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = cAudioFmt.AssignFormat(SPSF_22kHz16BitMono);
    }

    //Call SPBindToFile, a SAPI helper method,  to bind the audio stream to the file
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {

        hr = SPBindToFile( L"c:\\ttstemp.wav",  SPFM_CREATE_ALWAYS,
            &cpStream, & cAudioFmt.FormatId(),cAudioFmt.WaveFormatExPtr() );
    }

    //set the output to cpStream so that the output audio data will be stored in cpStream
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = cpVoice->SetOutput( cpStream, TRUE );
    }

    //Speak the text "hello world" synchronously
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = cpVoice->Speak( L"Hello World",  SPF_DEFAULT, NULL );
    }

    //close the stream
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = cpStream->Close();
    }

    //Release the stream and voice object    
    cpStream.Release ();
    cpVoice.Release();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You told use the HRESULT was an error code, but you didn't say what the code was.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy You're absolutely right. My apologies (I was late and I was returning to home to my girlfriend birthday party...). Next time I'll be more careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize the thread using [`CoInitialize[Ex]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) prior to using `CoCreateInstance` API. The error code you are getting should explicitly suggest that: `CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED` (you should have posted it on your question!).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It solved my problem. Sorry for missing error code, I'll be more careful next time. Thanks again.